# Resolving CAN Communication Issue: Decoding and Fixing 'BUSPASSIVE BUSWARNING'

Tags: arduino, can

I set up a communication system (J1939) using two MCP2515 modules connected to two Arduino UNO boards. Then, I added a PCAN USB interface to monitor messages using PCAN View Software. Everything was fine until I connected a controller's CAN to the line. Now, I can still read messages from one Arduino in both Serial Monitor and PCAN View, but in addition some lines shows an extra message:

```
322.2675,,Rx,,4,BUSPASSIVE BUSWARNING.
```

What does this warning mean and how I can fix it?

Comment: It means there's some manner of hardware problem present. See this CAN FAQ: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Error Passive* state means that the *Receive Error Counter* (REC) and/or *Transmit Error Counter* (TEC) have reached a value greater than 127 and TEC is less or equal to 255.

Various transmit and receive error events increment these error counters. For more detailed information, see [An Introduction to CAN](https://caxapa.ru/thumbs/721101/CAN.pdf#page=6) (page 6).

If the firmware and drivers are implemented correctly, some of the most common causes I have encountered (and the ones I'd recommend checking first) are:

- Are exactly two CAN terminating resistors installed to both ends of the bus? Incorrect termination could cause all kinds of bit errors.
- Double check the bus wiring. For example, if a transmitting node is disconnected from the bus (due to a cable break or the connector not properly connecting), no node can acknowledge the CAN message, causing TEC to rise to the *Error Passive* threshold.
- Are all nodes configured to the same baudrate?